# Segmentation Fault 11 with code blocks

Tags: c

I've been having some trouble with a program I'm making. Every time I try to compile it, I keep getting Segmentation Fault 11. I don't know why this is happening. I'm using Code Block IDE and whenever I Build and run, segmentation fault 11 continues to arise. Any ideas on how I can remedy this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMTEMPS 2881

int main(void){

    //opening the file with temperatures
    FILE * ifp;
    ifp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");

    //Declaring variables
    int i,j;
    int pct, num30 = 0, count_ac_h = 0, count_ac_t = 0, current_h = 0;
    int ac_on = 0, count_ac = 0;
    double temps[2881], pct_hr[24], diff, current_temp, previous_temp;



    //Checking the temperature from the .txt file and counting the occurences
    for (i = 0; i < 2881; ++i){
        fscanf(ifp, "%lf", &temps[i]);
    }

    previous_temp = temps[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 2881; ++i){
        if (num30 == 120){
            count_ac_t += count_ac_h;
            pct_hr[current_h] = (double)(count_ac_h/120);
            current_h++;
            count_ac_h = 0;
            num30 = 0;
        }

        current_temp = temps[i];
        diff = previous_temp - current_temp;
        if(diff > -0.5 && diff <0.5){
            if(ac_on == 1){
                count_ac_h++;
            }
        }

        else if (diff <= -0.5){
            if (ac_on == 0){
                ac_on = 1;
            count_ac_h++;
            }
        }

        else if (diff >= 0.5){
            if(ac_on == 1)
                ac_on = 0;
        }

        num30++;
        previous_temp = current_temp;
    }


    // Creating the bar graph based on results from above
    double pct_day = (double)(count_ac/NUMTEMPS);

    for (i = 20; i >= 0; i--){
    pct = i*5;
    for (j = 0; j < 24; ++j){
        if (pct > (pct_hr[j]*100))
            printf("_");
        else
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it under a debugger, it should tell you where (and why) it is crashing. Segmentation faults are typically due to using bad pointers.

Comment: Why `#define NUMTEMPS` to be 2881 and then continue to use the literal all over your code? Just use NUMTEMPS!

Comment: Which debugger would you recommend?

Comment: j is initialized at the top with i.

Comment: I would use gdb if you're on linux. If you run it there it'll tell you the exact line where you segfault.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 20; i >= 0; i--){
        pct = i*5;
        for (i = 0; i < 24; ++i){
            if (pct > (pct_hr[j]*100))
                printf("_");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
```

check this loop, use different loop variables for nested loops. here `j` is uninitialized so if it takes random large value it will result is segmentation fault.

Comment: @user3230393 ok. dont make changes to question to reflect the suggestions from answer. it makes the answer irrelevant. so roll back your question to original state.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
pct_hr[current_h] = (double)(count_ac_h/120);
```

How can you be sure `current_h` is never greater than 23?