# Segmentation Fault: 11, reading in files and pointers

Tags: c

I'm making a program that reads in a list of temperatures from a .txt file. After that I count the variances in temperature to see if the AC has been turned off or off. However, whenever I try to run my program I continue to receive a Segmentation Fault: 11 error. I don't know why this is occurring. I've thought that maybe it's because I need to close the *fp file that I'm opening. Other than that I don't know what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMTEMPS 2881


int main(void){

    //opening the file with temperatures
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");


    //Declaring variables
    int i,j;
    int pct, num30 = 0, count_ac_h = 0, count_ac_t = 0, current_h = 0;
    int ac_on = 0, count_ac = 0;
    double temps[2881], pct_hr[24], diff, current_temp, previous_temp;



    //Checking the temperature from the .txt file and counting the occurences
    for (i = 0; i < NUMTEMPS; ++i){
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &temps[i]);
    }

    previous_temp = temps[0];
    for (i = 0; i < NUMTEMPS; ++i){
        if (num30 == 120){
            count_ac_t += count_ac_h;
            pct_hr[current_h] = (double)(count_ac_h/120);
            current_h++;
            count_ac_h = 0;
            num30 = 0;
        }

        current_temp = temps[i];
        diff = previous_temp - current_temp;
        if(diff > -0.5 && diff <0.5){
            if(ac_on == 1){
                count_ac_h++;
            }
        }

        else if (diff <= -0.5){
            if (ac_on == 0){
                ac_on = 1;
            count_ac_h++;
            }
        }

        else if (diff >= 0.5){
            if(ac_on == 1)
                ac_on = 0;
        }

        num30++;
        previous_temp = current_temp;
    }


    // Creating the bar graph based on results from above
    double pct_day = (double)(count_ac/NUMTEMPS);

    for (i = 20; i >= 0; i--){
        pct = i*5;
        for (j = 0; j < 24; ++j){
            if (pct > (pct_hr[i]*100))
                printf("_");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you run your code in a debugger?  That's what they are for.

Comment: what debugger would you recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation Fault 11 with code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515954/segmentation-fault-11-with-code-blocks)

Comment: Well, you don't specify what OS you are using, or compiler.

Comment: Yes, I fixed some code from the other post but still have not gotten any farther @SørenDebois.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm using CodeBlocks for mac with a GCC compiler

Comment: I think you might be mistaking Stackoverflow for a debugging service. There were good suggestions in the answers and comments for your previous question; including firing up a debugger. Why not try to follow some of those before you come back?

Answer (score 0):

You never check fp to be a valid file pointer after fopen() (!= NULL).

Not unlikely (actually, I'll bet on it) your program just doesn't find its data file.

Comment: WHat would help it find it's data file? Putting them in the same folder? At the moment they're on my desktop.

Comment: first it would help to do what I wrote: programmatically check if you get a valid FILE pointer after fopen() (and write an appropriate error message if not) before you use it.